# Extract Graphql queries sent by a browser application with Apollo client

Tags: graphql, postman, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to simplify the process of exporting GraphQL queries sent by my application for documentation purposes. For the record, I want to be able to paste those queries into Postman collections.

Here are my different approaches:

- Relying on .graphql files: first it's still very difficult to setup with a full fledged TypeScript + Webpack + Babel setup (using Next.js). Anyway, it does not provide variables, so you only have half the query.
- Relying on the network tab. From there, we can copy queries content and import into Postman. Combined with Cypress it could provide an awesome workflow. It works OK, but Apollo Client will send queries as JSON objects, difficult to interpret
- I tried to use the "application/graphql" content-type. It's way more readable and available in Postman. BUUUT it is non-standard, and thus not available in Apollo client.

So my question is rather open, but what are the possibilities to enable extracting graphql queries (and variables) sent by my browser and inject them into Postman?
Most promising solution is enabling "application/graphql" client side, or converting the JSON representation back to a string representation. But I could explore another possibility (eg using Apollo Engine as an intermediate)

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is to use the [`apollo` CLI tool](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling). It includes a [`client:extract`](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling/#apollo-clientextract-output) command that extracts all of the GraphQL operations/documents in your application into a file. You run the tool on your JS(X)/TS(X) files and it extracts the GraphQL documents into a file that looks like this (this output is the result of pointing the tool at a single file containing a single query):

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "operations": [
    {
      "signature": "b4f318e6aebcc3631bc88eedef09c6001bb8c310917e97ee6df4a99e17c3c056",
      "document": "query BootstrapQuery{user:viewer{__typename delivery_time_1 delivery_time_2 devices{__typename fcm_token id notification{__typename enabled}}has_password id label location name next_delivery_string oauths{__typename email id name picture provider}plan plan_billing_service plan_expires plan_since plan_will_renew profile_picture recovery_email timezone username}}",
      "metadata": {
        "engineSignature": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can then use that file however you want.

In my case, I use this tool to publish an [allow-list of operations](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/deployment/allow-list.html) to Hasura. I'm not sure what you mean by injecting queries into Postman, but I think this tool may provide you with an automated start that would be an improvement over manual copy/pasting.

Comment: Sounds awesome, but can you please clarify the usage? Does it read the code statically or intercept queries from the browser?
Another lead I found is [node-fetch-har](https://github.com/exogen/node-fetch-har) which can intercept all queries from `fetch` (so including Apollo client) in the same format the browser Network Tools is using.

Comment: It's a CLI tool that reads the code statically. I updated the answer with an example.